# Overclocking with Ubuntu

Tags: intel, cpu, cpufreq, overclocking

I overclocked my CPU in BIOS using a multiplier. Everything in Ubuntu still shows the CPU frequency is stock. Is the CPU running at stock frequency, or is it overclocked like it's supposed to be? Is there a utility that shows the accurate frequency (like CPUZ for windows)?

edit: Specifically when typing 'lscpu' into Terminal, or viewing CPU info in the settings it shows stock frequency. CPUZ (windows app) also shows stock frequency under the CPU info, but there is another section that shows the actual frequency that the CPU is running at. Any way to access that info in Ubuntu?

Comment: What is _Everything in Ubuntu_ you are talking about, where you see the frequency? New Intel CPUs all have automatic power adjustment, and overclocking changes the maximum clock speed, not the standard operating speed. You will only likely "see" higher clock speeds, when it is necessary (like when playing a heavy 3D game in Steam, for example). See https://superuser.com/questions/758408/overclocking-and-intel-speedstep-in-gnu-linux for example.

Comment: For example under System settings, Details. It lists the CPU there along with the frequency. I also set the clock speed to non-adaptive, so it should be fixed at the overclocked frequency. I also have InfoPanel installed and it shows the stock frequency. Same with Sysmonitor screenlet. Also when I type 'lscup' into Terminal, it says the CPU Frequency is 3.2, which is stock.

Comment: Run _sudo dmidecode -t processor_ and check the speed and voltage reported there.

Comment: That still shows the stock frequency.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can install i7z using

```
sudo apt-get install i7z
```

and then run it with `sudo i7z`, stress your cpu using something like handbrake, and during encoding, clock speeds will be shown accurately. Sadly right now i7z doesn't show temperatures but I think they will be added in future versions.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Intel-CPU then execute this in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install msr-tools

sudo modprobe msr
sudo rdmsr -p"0" 0x1a0 -f 38:38
```

If this returns 1 execute this.

```
sudo modprobe msr

#Dual-Core:
sudo wrmsr -p"0" 0x1a0 0x850089
sudo wrmsr -p"1" 0x1a0 0x850089

#or

#Quad-Core:
sudo wrmsr -p"0" 0x1a0 0x850089
sudo wrmsr -p"1" 0x1a0 0x850089
sudo wrmsr -p"2" 0x1a0 0x850089
sudo wrmsr -p"3" 0x1a0 0x850089
```

Comment: Can you tell me the required bits for 32 bit systems?

Comment: should be the same